# CONTAINS cannot find the item that LIKE does

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a table `Player` that has player with name `Emre Can`. However, I cannot get it using `contains` like below:

```
SELECT  [Id], [Name]      
FROM [Player]
where contains(name,'"*Can*"')  -- show 10 results without emre can
```

José Cañas, Lorik Cana, ... but no Emre Can

However, if I use

```
SELECT  [Id],[Name]      
FROM [Player]
where name like '%Can%'  -- work fine??

where contains(name,'"*Emre*"')  -- also works fine
```

UPDATE: It seems Can is listed on the stop lists.

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON Player SET STOPLIST = OFF -- works now
```

Answer (score 1):

Contains can be used to search a prefix, not a suffix and ill not work like the "LIKE" string operator.
Please refer to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

**Edit**

After a search found this **not recommended** hack you can use to allow sufix search

Add a column in your table which stores the reverse of the string
like

```
SET NewColumnName = REVERSE(ColumnName)

CREATE PROCEDURE sps_searchSuffix(@searchString varchar(8000)) AS

SET @searchString = REVERSE(@searchString)

DECLARE @Q nVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Q = 'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CONTAINS (ColumnName,''"'+@searchString+'*"'''+')'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Q
```

And call it like this if you want to search "garding" and you have a data like "regarding"

```
DECLARE @ST VARCHAR(500)
SET @ST = 'garding'
PRINT @ST
EXEC sps_searchSuffix @ST
```

found [here](http://www.sqlhelpline.com/2009/05/search-suffix-using-full-text-search-in.html)